# Getting an error when combining Google play service with Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, maps, google-play-services

I'm delivering this so soon, please help me.

I got these errors when I added Firebase to my app, which had Google maps already and worked well:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout100Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage900Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon900Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoCore222Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIdlingResource222Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestExposedInstrumentationApiPublish05Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRules05Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRunner05Library
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Running dex as a separate process.
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 1433 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space: failed reallocation of scalar replaced objects
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 14 mins 26.008 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and my build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "petersamir.elmasna3"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and my manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="petersamir.elmasna3">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="petersamir.elmasna3.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm delivering this so soon. Again, please help me

Comment: Are you properly implementing the Multidex application? When using Multidex you need to have a class which extends MultidexApplication and initialises it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved when i removed the design dependency which comes with basic activity and the dependencies now are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
```